# flex : how to remove playcontrols in fullscreen?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a s:VideoPlayer in flex4
I can remove playerControls with: video1.playerControls.visible=false

But I want to remove them in FullScreen:

I tried with:

```
    protected function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void {
        trace("fullscreen="+event.fullScreen);
        video1.playerControls.visible = false;//                
    }
```

No effect !
Infact once entered in fullscreenmode, it seems I have no more control over the player at all : ex: my watermark logo is not visible anymore, I cannot make the buttons invisible.

ANy clue ?

regards

Comment: Why do you want to remove the controls? As far as I am aware, this is _highly_ discouraged by Adobe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation of spark.components.VideoPlayer says here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoPlayer.html#SkinPartSummary) `VideoPlayer.playerControls` is a skin part. The `playerControls` skin part's purpose is to determine which controls will fade out when you do not interact with the video player in any way while in full screen. So the player behaves like nearly all players do: it hides controls if the user does nothing.

Maybe that's the behavior you tried to (re)implement. But if you want to display completely nothing when the player switches to full screen you should create a new Spark Skin for the Video Player instead. Usually it is not meaningful to change skin parts directly like you did.

To create a new Skin for the Player in Flash Builder you can go to *File > New > MXML-Skin*.
Then you select the VideoPlayer class as the so-called *host component* and give your new skin a name. By default Flash Builder copies the content of the standard skin class to your custom skin so will get a working skin.

If you do not use Flash Builder you can go to the following directory in your Flex SDK installation folder ***/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins/spark/*** and open the ***VideoPlayerSkin.mxml*** file. Copy the whole content to your own skin class and start modifying it.

When you've set up your skin for changes you also need to tell the player to use your skin. This can be done by adding some CSS information:

```
s|VideoPlayer
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("com.company.skins.MyVideoPlayerSkin");
}
```

Now you can change the your skin by modifying the `playerControls` skin part. It is located somewhere in the middle of the skin's MXML file (in SDK version 4.5.1 its at line 131).
To hide the `playerControls` element in full screen you add `visible.fullScreenStates="false"` to its attributes. This should solve your issue.